# JavaScript removed in SharePoint Publishing Page during edit

Tags: javascript, publishing-page

I was working on a migration of an existing site to SharePoint and when pasting the source code of the pages to the SharePoint RichText fields in the edit mode of the page, I tried to copy the HTML into the editor but the inline javascript code was completely removed.

How do I address it?

I have added 4 RichTextBoxes where I have put the HTML of an existing page and it displays correctly. If I use the whole definition in one of the textboxes, the other textboxes cannot use it as out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd need to use "Content Editor Web Parts" if you're pasting in javascript which you intend to have working in a SharePoint page.

Comment: As a (very) late addition, use the HTML Form web part if you're using SharePoint 2010.